# How to get form-data from PUT request using Flask-restplus

Tags: rest, flask, multipartform-data, put

One of the endpoints of my API handles PUT request with multipart/form-data. While an audio file is uploaded, some other data is sent from client in form-data. I am able to receive the file using the following code, but am having trouble getting the form-data.

```
@api.route('/upload')
class AudioUpload(Resource):
    def put(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        filename = now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S") + ".mp3"
        cwd = os.getcwd()
        filepath = os.path.join(cwd, filename)
        name = request.form['name']
        print('name: ', name, file=sys.stdout)
        with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(request.stream.read())
        return filepath
```

The curl command I tested with is:

```
curl -X PUT \
  http://localhost:5000/api/upload \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data \
  -F file=@Audio-3791_244-Feb_04_2018-13_30_04.wav \
  -F name=xyz
```

I got 400 with error `The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

What is the correct way getting form-data in PUT request?

**EDIT**

Just tried the same code with post. It does not work for getting the form-data either with same error.